# Tooltip vanishes after it gets displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

Following method is fired, when login button is clicked. When any of the field is empty, tooltip gets displayed. But the same tooltip gets hidden, when the button is pressed again (with the empty field). What could be the reason for this?

```
$('#loginform .login-validation').tooltip('hide');
$('#loginform .login-validation').parent().removeClass('has-error');
$('#loginform .login-validation').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).val()) {
        error = true;
        $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
        var errorField = $(this).attr('dname').charAt(0).toUpperCase() +  $(this).attr('dname').slice(1);
        var errorMessage = errorField + ' cannot be left blank';
        $(this).attr('data-original-title',errorMessage); // Set ToolTip message
        $(this).tooltip('show');
        return false;
    }else {
        userObject[$(this).attr('dname')] = $(this).val().trim();
    }
});
```

`Markup`:

```
<div class="input-group input-field username-field">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-trigger="manual" id="usname" type="text" class="form-control login-validation" name="usname" autocomplete="off" placeholder="username" dname="username">                                        
 </div>

  <div class="input-group input-field password-field">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
            <input data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-trigger="manual" id="pswd" name="pswd" type="password" class="form-control login-validation" placeholder="password" dname="password">
   </div>
```

Submit Button markup on request by @NikhilNanjappa:

```
<div class="form-group btn-container">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                      <input type="hidden" name="FormValues" id="FormValues" value="" />
                      <button type='submit' id="loginButton" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Scenario:

1. Fields are left empty.
2. Login button is pressed.
3. Error tooltip gets displayed.
4. Login button is pressed again. The same tooltip vanishes. What could be the reason for this?
5. `$(this).show()` triggers the tooltip when initially they were hidden by `$('#loginform .login-validation').tooltip('hide')` but vanishes as soon as the control passes out of the function scope.

**Note:**

It works fine, if the statement :

```
$('#loginform .login-validation').tooltip('hide');
```

is removed.

Comment: can you please provide the necessary markup code etc.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Edited.

Comment: Login button code please...thanks

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Already given above.

Comment: I mean the login `<button>` code. I can just see 2 input fields according to your code.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Why would you need that?

Comment: how do you expect us to trigger the validation without a submit button ? We are trying to help you debug it, so you need to give the entire code to eliminate any errors. You mentioned **Step 2**. You expect us to debug without the steps you yourself mentioned ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Alright, if that helps!

Comment: Something happening in `emulateTransitionEnd` function from `bootstrap.js`. I've tried with `tooltip.js` without bootstrap js and it works as it should, must be a bug or something in `bootstrap.js`